# Dropping multiple columns of Spark DataFrame in Java

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm using Spark 1.5.3, I tried separating the even and odd columns in a spark dataFrame,

```
String filePath = "/home/inputData.txt";
DataFrame inputDataFrame = sql.read().format("com.databricks.spark.csv") //No I18N
    .option("inferSchema", "true") //No I18N
    .option("delimiter", ",") //No I18N
    .option("header", "false") //No I18N
    .load(filePath);

inputDataFrame.show();

List<String> evenColumns = Arrays.asList("C0", "C2", "C4", "C6", "C8", "C10", "C12");
DataFrame oddDataFrame = inputDataFrame.na().drop(JavaConversions.asScalaBuffer(evenColumns));
DataFrame evenDataFrame = inputDataFrame.selectExpr(JavaConversions.asScalaBuffer(evenColumns));

evenDataFrame.show();
oddDataFrame.show();
```

Output for the above code :

inputDataFrame:

```
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| C0| C1| C2| C3| C4| C5| C6| C7| C8| C9|C10|C11|C12|C13|
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|  0|  0|  0|  0|  1|  0|  0|  0|  2|  3|  2|  2|  0|  5|
|  1|  5|  6|  0| 14|  0|  5|  0| 95|  2|120|  0|  0|  9|
|  1|  6|  1|  0|  3|  0|  4|  0| 21| 22| 11|  0|  0| 23|
|  1|  0|  1|  0|  1|  0|  4|  0|  1|  4|  2|  0|  0|  5|
|  1| 37|  9|  0| 19|  0| 31|  0| 87|  9|108|  0|  0|170|
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

evenDataFrame:

```
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| C0| C2| C4| C6| C8|C10|C12|
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|  0|  0|  1|  0|  2|  2|  0|
|  1|  6| 14|  5| 95|120|  0|
|  1|  1|  3|  4| 21| 11|  0|
|  1|  1|  1|  4|  1|  2|  0|
|  1|  9| 19| 31| 87|108|  0|
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

oddDataFrame:

```
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| C0| C1| C2| C3| C4| C5| C6| C7| C8| C9|C10|C11|C12|C13|
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|  0|  0|  0|  0|  1|  0|  0|  0|  2|  3|  2|  2|  0|  5|
|  1|  5|  6|  0| 14|  0|  5|  0| 95|  2|120|  0|  0|  9|
|  1|  6|  1|  0|  3|  0|  4|  0| 21| 22| 11|  0|  0| 23|
|  1|  0|  1|  0|  1|  0|  4|  0|  1|  4|  2|  0|  0|  5|
|  1| 37|  9|  0| 19|  0| 31|  0| 87|  9|108|  0|  0|170|
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

Dropping the `evenColumns` isn't performed in the above dataFrame. What I'm doing wrong? Expected output is

```
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| C1| C3| C5| C7| C9|C11|C13|
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
|  0|  0|  0|  0|  3|  2|  5|
|  5|  0|  0|  0|  2|  0|  9|
|  6|  0|  0|  0| 22|  0| 23|
|  0|  0|  0|  0|  4|  0|  5|
| 37|  0|  0|  0|  9|  0|170|
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

Comment: Did you manage to solve the problem?

Comment: @Shaido.. Yes I solved the problem, but it is a work around approach.

Comment: Just curious, any reason the other answer (maybe I should note it's written by me) did not work in your case?

Comment: @Shaido I think your answer `inputDataFrame.drop(JavaConversions.asScalaBuffer(evenColumns));` will work for Dataset<Row> Spark 2.x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an indirect/ work around approach

```
public static DataFrame drop(DataFrame dataFrame, List<String> dropCol) {
List<String> colname = Arrays.stream(dataFrame.columns()).filter(col -> !dropCol.contains(col)).collect(Collectors.toList());
// colname list will have the names of the cols except the ones to be dropped.
return dataFrame.selectExpr(JavaConversions.asScalaBuffer(colname));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`na().drop` is used to drop rows containing null or NaN values. To drop columns regardless of what they contain, simply use `drop()`. In this case it should be:

```
inputDataFrame.drop(JavaConversions.asScalaBuffer(evenColumns));
```